# How to speed up reading matrices from file and multiplying them?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

1 What I have on input
File input.txt looking like this:

> 3 2
>   1 2
>
> 1 2
>   3 4
>
> 4 2
>   1 3
>
> 1 2
>   2 1

Where:
3 2   3-number of matrices in file; 2-length of matrices (they all square)
1 2   i=1 j=2 -positions of requested value inmatrixResult[i][j]

1 2   matrix 1
3 4

4 2   matrix 2
1 3

1 2   matrix 3
2 1

Number of matrices can be any <=130
Matrices size can be any <=130

2 What should I have on output
One number, which is member of result matrix, specified by position values (1, 2 in this case).
Where result matrix=matrix 1 * matrix 2
For example final result is: 20

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by Pazuk on 28.01.2018.
 */

// Main idea:
// Step 1. Get all values from input file and according with it build array with numbers for matrices
// Step 2.
// Loop iteration:
// - get numbers from array and create next matrix array
// - multiply actual matrix with next matrix, get result matrix
// - mark result matrix as actual matrix
// Next iteration...
// Step 3. After last iteration, get from result matrix requested number (positions specified in input file)


public class Main {


    static int[] list;

    static boolean fileCheckOk=true;
    static int m;
    static int n;
    static int a;
    static int b;


    static int[][] matrixA;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println(time);

        readFile();

        time = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
        System.out.println(time);

        if(fileCheckOk){
            calculate();

            PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter("output.txt");
            writer.print(matrixA[a-1][b-1]);
            writer.close();
        }

        time = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
        System.out.println(time);
    }

    static void readFile() throws IOException {

       Reader reader=new FileReader(file);
       StreamTokenizer tokenizer=new StreamTokenizer(reader);

       //general input values:
       tokenizer.nextToken();
       m=(int)tokenizer.nval; // number of matricis
       tokenizer.nextToken();
       n=(int)tokenizer.nval; // matrices size
       tokenizer.nextToken();
       a=(int)tokenizer.nval; // position i of requested number
       tokenizer.nextToken();
       b=(int)tokenizer.nval; // position j of requested number                

       list=new int[m*n*n]; // array length according with quantity of matricis and their size
       int i=0;
       while(tokenizer.nextToken()!=StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
           list[i]=(int)tokenizer.nval;
           i++;
       }

       if(reader!=null) {
               reader.close();
       }

        /*if(m>=1 && m<=130 && n>=1 && n<=130 && a>=1 && a<=n && b>=1 && b<=n){
            fileCheckOk=true;
        }*/
    }

    static void calculate(){ // calculate matrices

        int f, i, j, k;
        int r=0;
        int t;
        int temp;
        int[] thatColumn=new int[n];
        int[] thisRow=new int[n];
        int result=0;

        matrixA=new int[n][n]; // actual matrix
        for(f=0; f< m; f++){ // number of iterations==matrices quantity
            int[][] matrixB=new int[Main.n][Main.n]; // next matrix
            for(i=0; i< Main.n; i++){
                for(j=0; j< Main.n; j++){
                    matrixB[i][j]=list[r];
                    r++;
                }
            }

            if(f>0){
                int[][] matrixC=new int[Main.n][Main.n]; //result matrix

                for(j=0; j< Main.n; j++){
                    for(k=0; k< Main.n; k++){
                        thatColumn[k]=matrixB[k][j];
                    }

                    for(i=0; i< Main.n; i++){
                        thisRow=matrixA[i];
                        result=0;
                        for(k=0; k<Main.n; k++){
                            temp=thisRow[k]*thatColumn[k];                                
                            result=result+temp;                                
                        }
                         matrixC[i][j]=result;
                    }
                }

                /*for(i=0; i< Main.n; i++){
                    for(j=0; j< Main.n; j++){
                        t=matrixA[i][k];
                        for(j=0; j< Main.n; j++){
                            temp=t*matrixB[k][j]; // multiplying...                                
                            matrixC[i][j]=matrixC[i][j]+temp; // ...matrces                                
                        }
                    }
                }*/

                matrixA=matrixC;                    
            } else {
                matrixA=matrixB;                    
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My code works and gives on output right value. But this code don't pass test. Because of it works too slow.

What can I do to make this do it faster?

Maybe #1. Process info from file other way? Now i scan nextInt. First
4 put into variables. All left into int[ ] array ( look readFile() method ).
And after take values for A, B, ect. matrices from this array.

Maybe #2. Change way of multiplying of matrices? Now I do it with
basic "direct" way:

```
 for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
             for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                 for(int k=0; k<o; k++){
                     resultMatrix[i][j]+=mA[i][k]*mB[k][j]; 
                 }
             }
         }
```

Well, almost this way. A bit faster ( look calculate( ) method ).

Maybe #3. Make calculations (or something other) in parallel threads?

Maybe #4. Instead of: "build" A and B matrices from int[ ] array values
at first for multiply them after Try to: make calculation of
resultMatrix using directly values from one-dimensional array int [ ]?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm, or just google fast matrix multiplication, of course thinking on your own first is best...

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy that's a big cannon for a 130x130 matrix, isn't it? Subdiving the matrix into blocks which fit into cache, and processing the blocks with multiple threads should be good enough. Some hints for the real-world, if that wasn't an exercise: 1) Don't re-implement matmul 2) Don't reimplement it in Java.

Comment: That's why I said 'thinking on your own is best' ...